# why is my pdf file to save bar charts created by matplotlib blank

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf

## code...The graph displays fine, but can't be saved...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def PlotThreadCountGraph( logfile ):
    with open(logfile,'r') as fin:

        for line in fin:
    #.
    #.

    #build data for graph
    fin.close()

#Draw the graph ...
pages =  range(0,len(t1))
plt.xlabel("Page (" + str(period)+" secs)")
plt.ylabel("Thread Counts")
plt.title("Some Title")

data = np.array([t1, t2, t3, t4,t5])
labels= ['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5']
bottom = np.vstack((np.zeros((data.shape[1],), dtype=data.dtype),np.cumsum(data, axis=0)[:-1]))
colors = ('magenta', 'green', 'blue', 'red','gray')
for dat, col, bot,lab in zip(data, colors, bottom,labels):
    plt.bar(pages, dat,label=lab, color=col, bottom=bot)
plt.legend(loc='best',ncol=2)

#plt.plot()
fig=plt.figure()
pdf.savefig(fig)
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)




pdf = PdfPages("pdf_file_name")

PlotThreadCountGraph ("logfile1",pdf)
PlotThreadCountGraph ("logfile2,pdf)
PlotThreadCountGraph ("logfile3,pdf)
PlotThreadCountGraph ("logfile4,pdf)
pdf.close()
```

The pdf file gets created with 4 blank images.
I tried different permutations of plot,savefig, show, close in the PlotThreadCountGraph but could not get the graph to show in the file
I appreciate your help with this. Thanks

Comment: You create the figure `fig` *after* you plot things. So at that point nothing is in `fig`.

Comment: I tried that too, it is still blank::
    plt.plot()
    fig=plt.figure()
    pdf.savefig(fig)
    plt.close(fig)

Comment: First comment still applies. Make sure to create the figure before plotting anything to it.

Comment: That was it ! Thank you so much